# when solving for $~b~$ in $~x'=Ax+b~$, if $~u'(1) = 0~$ and $~u(1) = c~$ is it acceptable to use $~C~$ as part of the answer?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

So here's what I have as my solution.

Find $~x' = Ax + b~$,
Where 
$A = \begin{pmatrix}
       1&1\\
       0&2
     \end{pmatrix}$
and $B = \begin{pmatrix}
       e^{3t}\\
       e^{3t}
     \end{pmatrix}$

First find eigen vectors $~Ax~$ and fundamental matrix

$1)~~$ Eigen vectors are
$v_1$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
       1\\
       0
     \end{pmatrix}$
$v_2$= $\begin{pmatrix}
       1\\
       1
     \end{pmatrix}$
Thus the fundamental matrix $X$ = 
     $\begin{pmatrix}
   e^t&e^{2t}\\
   0&e^{2t}
 \end{pmatrix}$

Now get the $det$(X) = $e^{3t}$

Use cramers rule to find $u'_1$ and $u'_2$ and integrate to get $u_1$ and $u_2$ in order to define $b$ in terms of $x'$
$u'_1$ = $\begin{vmatrix}
   e^{3t}&e^{2t}\\
   e^{3t}&e^{2t}
 \end{vmatrix}$ / $e^{3t}$ = $0$

$u'_2$ = $\begin{vmatrix}
   e^{t}&e^{3t}\\
   0&e^{3t}
 \end{vmatrix}$ / $e^{3t}$ = $e^{t}$

integrate to get

$u_1$ = $C$

This makes me uncomfortable, I haven't seen anything like this in the book

$u_2$ = $e^{t}$

So $x_p(t) = X * u(t) =\begin{pmatrix}
   e^t&e^{2t}\\
   0&e^{2t}
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
   C\\
   e^{t}
 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
   Ce^{t}+e^{3t}\\
   e^{3t}
 \end{pmatrix}$ which is used as b

$x(t)=c_1e^{t}\begin{pmatrix}
   1\\
   0
 \end{pmatrix}+c_2e^{2t}\begin{pmatrix}
   1\\
   1
 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
   Ce^{t}+e^{3t}\\
   e^{3t}
 \end{pmatrix}$

I'm taking linear and diff eqs for the first time ever during the summer, so I'm sorry if I cant give more details, I don't feel $~100\%~$ familiar with everything and this procedure was done parallel to the book examples.

Here is the book example I am learning from.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wpW5.jpg

Here's my attempt
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PUYn.jpg

I would appreciate any kind of help thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, the constant $C$ does not matter. If you combine all the vectors, you get $$x(t) = \begin{pmatrix}c_1e^t + c_2e^{2t} + Ce^t + e^{3t}\\ c_2e^{2t} + e^{2t}\end{pmatrix}$$
whence the term $c_1e^t + Ce^t$ can be combined into one $C_2e^t$. I think in general if you have one of the terms in $u'$ equal to $0$, you can just integrate to $0$ without changing anything.

Comment: So i could just not write it as part of the answer?

Comment: Yeah. It's an unnecessary constant.